# Computing the log loss with Numpy of a 1d-array

Tags: python, numpy, rules, scoring

I have a CSV-file with my own estimated probabilities for the outcome of a soccer match. There are three possible outcomes: a win, a draw and a loss. In order to determine how accurate my estimates are, I want to see how they score on the log loss-scoring rule. In what follows I assume that:

- In each instance / football match) there are three possible outcomes (win/draw/loss)
- The model predictions for the outcomes are respective probabilities *P,1, P,2* and *P,3*
- The respective actual observed outcomes are *E,1, E,2* and *E,3*. So for football matches the *E,i's* are either 1 or 0 and in such cases the index of the actual observed outcome will be denoted *w*, so *E,i* is 1 if *i* is *w* and 0 otherwise.

My working script looks a follows

```
    import numpy as np

    def log_loss_score(predicted, actual, eps=1e-14):

        """
        :param predicted:   The predicted probabilities as floats between 0-1
        :param actual:      The binary labels. Either 0 or 1.
        :param eps:         Log(0) is equal to infinity, so we need to offset our predicted values slightly by eps from 0 or 1
        :return:            The logarithmic loss between between the predicted probability assigned to the possible outcomes for item i, and the actual outcome.
        """

        predicted = np.clip(predicted, eps, 1-eps)
        loss = -1 * np.mean(actual * np.log(predicted) + (1 - actual) * np.log(1-predicted))

        return loss


     predicted = [0.35, 0.3, 0.35]
     actual = [0, 1, 0] # the match ended in a draw
     for x in range(0, len(predicted)):
         log_loss = log_loss_score(predicted[x], actual[x])
         print(log_loss)
```

Running this script gives me the following output:

*0.4307829160924542
1.2039728043259361
0.4307829160924542*

I understand that is the log-loss of each match outcome prediction for a single match. But how can I transform this into a match-"broad" log-loss score?

**Question**: How can I calculate the log-loss score of the whole match if I have the log-loss score of each potential outcome?

Comment: What will be your input in case of `braod` log-loss. Please mention that.

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/113301/150976).

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is calculate the average log loss for all the outcomes.

```
log_loss=0
for x in range(0, len(predicted)):
     log_loss += log_loss_score(predicted[x], actual[x])
logloss = logloss/len(len(predicted))
print(log_loss)
```